# Python- add to dictionary based on an incrementing value in 2 lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, increment

I have 2 lists which i have created and added an incrementing value to each item. The reason being that the values in each list are to be joined together in a dictionary. However the values in each list are not a 1 to 1 pair..this is why i added the incrementing values to assist with associating each key with it's corresponding value(s).

Here is some example data from my lists:

```
list_a = ['abc|1','bcd|2','cde|3']
list_b = ['1234|1','2345|2','3456|2','4567|2','5678|3']
```

So ideally what i am looking to do is run through both lists and then produce a dictionary based on pairing by the incrementing values. I am guessing the values where applicable would have to be a list?

Below is the ideal output:

```
my_dict = {'abc|1':'1234|1','bcd|2':['2345|2','3456|2','4567|2'],'cde|3':'5678|3'}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses! It is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_a = ['abc|1','bcd|2','cde|3']
list_b = ['1234|1','2345|2','3456|2','4567|2','5678|3']

tmp = {k.split('|')[1]: (k, []) for k in list_a}
for v in list_b:
    tmp[v.split('|')[1]][1].append(v)
my_dict = dict(tmp.values())
```

This gets *close* to what you posted as goal, but I think it's actually better.

```
goal: {'abc|1':  '1234|1',  'bcd|2': ['2345|2', '3456|2', '4567|2'], 'cde|3':  '5678|3' }
mine: {'abc|1': ['1234|1'], 'bcd|2': ['2345|2', '3456|2', '4567|2'], 'cde|3': ['5678|3']}
```

You can see we only differ by putting singles into a list (me) or not (you). The reason I think my way is better is because any code *using* this result will likely be easier if *all* values are lists, so it doesn't need to handle both single strings and lists of strings. Just like it was easier for me to *produce* only lists.

But if you still prefer your way, change my above last line to:

```
my_dict = {k: v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k, v in tmp.values()}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i agree that putting singles into a list is the best way forward :)

Answer (score 2):

You could make two dicts grouping with the first:

```
list_a = ['abc|1','bcd|2','cde|3']
list_b = ['1234|1','2345|2','3456|2','4567|2','5678|3']

d = defaultdict(list)
from itertools import chain
for k in chain(list_a,list_b):
    d[k.rsplit("|",1)[1]].append(k)
print(d)

print({v[0]:v[1:] for v in d.values()})

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['abc|1', '1234|1'], '3': ['cde|3', '5678|3'], '2': ['bcd|2', '2345|2', '3456|2', '4567|2']})
{'abc|1': ['1234|1'], 'cde|3': ['5678|3'], 'bcd|2': ['2345|2', '3456|2', '4567|2']}
```

You can avoid the list for single values by checking the length first if required.

```
d = {v[0]: (v[1:] if len(v)> 2 else v[-1]) for v in d.values()}
print(d)

{'abc|1': '1234|1', 'cde|3': '5678|3', 'bcd|2': ['2345|2', '3456|2', '4567|2']}
```

Using python3 the syntax is a bit nicer using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
d = {k: (val if len(val) > 1 else val[0]) for k,*val in d.values()}
print(d)
```

If you want order based on the keys in the lista you will need an OrderedDict:

```
list_a = ['abc|1', 'bcd|2', 'cde|3']
list_b = ['1234|1', '2345|2', '3456|2', '4567|2', '5678|3']
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

od = OrderedDict()

for k in chain(list_a, list_b):
    od.setdefault(k.rsplit("|",1)[1], []).append(k)

d = OrderedDict((k, (val)) for k, *val in od.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved from something like this

```
temp_dict = {}
for x in list_a:
    val = x.split('|')[1]
    temp_dict[x] = [y for y in list_b if y.endswith("|" + val)]
```

Comment: The solution will fail if `val` go up to 11.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I guess now it should do... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very readable code, it should be clear enough but if you have doubt on it please comment. You can use OrderedDict instead of a normal dict() if you want to keep the the order of the key as they are added to the dictionary.

```
list_a = ['abc|1','bcd|2','cde|3']
list_b = ['1234|1','2345|2','3456|2','4567|2','5678|3']

d = dict()
for item in list_a:
    d.update({item:[]}) # initialize the dictionary
    value_a = item.split('|')[1] # extract the number from the item of list_a
    for thing in list_b:
        value_b = thing.split('|')[1] # extract the number from the item of list_b
        if value_a == value_b: # if the numbers are the same
            d[item].append(thing) # append the item of list_b into the dictionary


print(d)
```